# Searching over multiple columns in multiple tables with i18n normalization

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I'm working on a project where we need a search function. The user enters a search term (possibly containing wildcards) into a text field, and we need to search a predefined set of columns (around 20) in 3 different tables. The search should also normalize international characters like `á==a`, `ç==c` etc.

The straightforward way of doing this is to build a giant query and let Oracle do the work. But I'm a bit concerned about performance as well as maintainability.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
    normalize(column1) LIKE normalize(searchstring) OR
    normalize(column2) LIKE normalize(searchstring) ...
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE
    normalize(column3) LIKE normalize(searchstring) OR
    normalize(column4) LIKE normalize(searchstring) ...
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE
    normalize(column5) LIKE normalize(searchstring) OR
    normalize(column6) LIKE normalize(searchstring) ...
```

We also considered using SOLR, but that would take a bit of installation and maintenance effort, which we would like to avoid.

The third option would be using some of Oracle's builtin features. However, I couldn't find anything that matches our specific requirements.

So this is a two part question:

- What is the best way to write the queries without any indexing? How can normalization be achieved?
- Is there a way to use some Oracle's feature to make it easier? (Multi-column indexes...?)

Answer (score 0):

If you could store the column and table names in a table, I'd do something like this-

```
FUNCTION user_search (search_string_in VARCHAR2(4000))
RETURN NUMBER
AS
    temp_num NUMBER;
    return_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR search_rec in (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM local_table)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' ||  search_rec.table_name ||
          ' WHERE '||search_rec.column_name||' = '|| search_string_in
          INTO temp_num;

          return_num := return_num + temp_num;
    END LOOP;

    return return_num;
END;
```

Obviously you'd need to change whatever your return value is and handle for exceptions, etc. but this would be much easier than one giant select query.